# How to train using batch inputs with Keras, but predicting with single example with an LSTM?

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, lstm

I have a a list of training data that I am using to train. However, when I predict, the prediction will be done online with a single example at a time.

If I declare my model with input like the following

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(64, batch_input_shape=(100, 5, 1), activation='tanh'))
model.add(LSTM(32, stateful=True))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
optimizer = SGD(lr=0.0005)
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=optimizer)
```

When I go to predict with a single example of shape (1, 5, 1), it gives the following error.

```
ValueError: Shape mismatch: x has 100 rows but z has 1 rows
```

The solution I came up with was to just train my model iteratively using a batch_input_shape of (1,5,1) and calling fit for each single example. This is incredibly slow.

Is there not a way to train on a large batch size, but predict with a single example using LSTM?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
model2 = Sequential()
model2.add(Dense(64, batch_input_shape=(1, 5, 1), activation='tanh')) 
model2.add(LSTM(32, stateful=True))
model2.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
optimizer2 = SGD(lr=0.0005)
model2.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=optimizer)

for nb, layer in enumerate(model.layers):
    model2.layers[nb].set_weights(layer.get_weights())
```

You are simply rewritting weights from one model to another.

Comment: This seems to work. I think I tried this before, but I did it by calling get and set on the model which didn't work for some reason. I didn't try layer by layer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the `input_shape` in the first layer. Therefore sending a shape that does not match the preset-ed `input_shape` is in valid.

There are two way to achieve that:
You can modify your model by changing 
`batch_input_shape=(100, 5, 1)`
to 
`input_shape=(5, 1)` to avoid a preset-ed batch size. You can setup the `batch_size=100` in `model.fit()`.

**Edit: Method 2**

You define the exact same model as `model2`. Then `model2.set_weights(model1.get_weights())`.

If you want to use `stateful==True`, you actually want to use the hidden layers from the last batch  as the initial states for the next batch. Therefore very  batch size should be matched. Otherwise, you can just remove the `stateful==True`.

Comment: I have tried that. When using an LSTM layer with stateful=True it gives the error "If a RNN is stateful, a complete input_shape must be provided (including batch size)."